# Multiplying linear differential operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This seems like such a simple thing but I can't get it to work. I have two linear differential operators

$$ L_1 = x\text D - 2 \text{ and } L_2 = (x+2)\text D + (x+1) $$

and a function

$$ f(x) = a x^2 + b\exp(-x) $$

Now, I have that

$$ L_1 f(x) = g(x) = -b(x+2)\exp(-x) $$

and that

$$ L_2 g(x) = 0 $$

so reasonably, I should have

$$ L_2 L_1 f(x) = Lf(x) = 0 $$

but when I multiply them, I get

$$ L = (x^2+2x)\text D^2 + (x^2 - x - 4)\text D - (2x+2) $$

and I find that

$$ Lf(x) = -(x+2)(2ax - b\exp(-x)) = -(x+2)f'(x) \neq 0 $$

I was under the impression that linear differential operators could be multiplied as polynomials to perform composition, but it doesn't seem to work here.

However, for a different set of operators

$$ M_1 = \text D+1 \text{ and } M_2 = (x^2+2x)\text D - (2x+2) $$

I get the product as

$$ M = (x^2 + 2x)\text D^2 + (x^2 - 2)\text D - (2x+2) $$

and

$$ Mf(x) = 0 $$

so it seems to work fine for this set.

What's going on here? Why does it work for one but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes differential operator don't commute.
$$L_1L_2 \ne L_2L_1$$
Your $L$ operator should be:
$$L=L_2L_1$$
$$L=(x^2+2x+2)D+x(x+2)D^2-2(x+1)$$
Note that $L_1,L_2$ don't commute:
$$L_1L_2=-(x+4)D+x(x+2)D^2-(x+2)\ne L$$
And as you noted in the comment:
$$(xD)D \ne D(xD)$$
Since:
$$(xD)D=xD^2$$
And:
$$D(xD)=D+xD^2$$

Comment: I see, I guess the issue is that (for example) $\text D (x\text D) \neq x \text D^2$, you still need to follow the product rule with these operators. Then it makes sense that as long as one of the two is has only constant coefficients, you should be able to multiply them as polynomials and therefore they would commute. But when both have variable coefficients, that's no longer guaranteed.

Comment: In fact you have that $D xD=D+xD^2$ so yes ity's different since you differentiate a product so it gives two terms not one. @AlexanderJ93 most of the time differential operators dont commute. You need to check.